# find blocks in sparse matrix (matlab)

Tags: matlab, graph, sparse-matrix, connected-components

I have symmetrical sparse matrices. Some of the elements would form "blocks" or "components" .
Please look at the output of spy on example matrix.
I want to efficiently find those clusters in MATLAB.

This problem is equivalent to finding connected components of a graph, however I have a feeling that relevant functionality should be available as a (combination of) fast MATLAB built-in functions that operate on sparse matrices.

Can you suggest such combination?

[image: sparse matrix with clusters]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found `graphconncomp` function in bioinformatics toolbox. It uses some mex routines internally.

Comment: @RobertStettler It says I can't accept my own answer for another 2 days, sorry.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96395/set-my-own-question-as-solved